# Insert a text column

Tags: notepad++

Using Notepad++:
I want a fast, plain and simple solution:
How can I insert a comma in a specific column space between texts?
I just want to make this file comma-delimitted to be exported to others.
Cannot use replace because the column has spaces, and there are many other fields that can be affected.

Comment: It's hard to advise, as you have not provided any sample data. Notepad++ supports regex so perhaps that can help. Or use some sort of sed/awk tool to help.

Comment: @COY please provide some example of what you're trying to achieve. Now it's not clear what the task is.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you have the following text:

```
18.0     month   12.5  text1    text2   text3
141.9     month   12.5  text1    text2   text3
52.8     month   12.5  text1  text2   text3
59.9     month   12.5  text1    text2   text3
36.4     month   12.5  text1    text2   text3
51.8     month   12.5  text1  text2   text3
68.0     month   12.5  text1    text2   text3
```

**For keyboard use:**

- Position the cursor in the desired column e.g. in front of `month`
- Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and move down with cursor key
- The cursor becomes a vertical line
- Write any text e.g. comma

**For mouse use:**

- Position the cursor in the desired column e.g. in front of `month`
- Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and move the mouse exactly vertically downwards
- The cursor becomes a vertical line
- Write any text e.g. comma

Repeat steps for the desired columns. Use it in two steps for special cases like shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Copy data from excel > paste in notepad++ > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> > (with search mode = extended) replace: `\t` with: `,`  > Done.

That should do. Please share if it works/not.

p/s : `\t` is the typical symbol for <kbd>Tab</kbd> character.